# how to pick random items from a list while avoiding picking the same item in a row

Tags: python, list, random

I want to iterate through list with random values. However, I want the item that has been picked to be removed from the list for the next trial, so that I can avoid picking the same item in a row; but it should be added back again after.

please help me on showing that on this simple example.
Thank you

```
import random
    l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
    for i in l:
        print random.choice(l)
```

Comment: Define what you mean by after. As in, when the program reruns? Or, it should only be removed for the next attempt.

Comment: Are the input values guaranteed to be unique? Would you expect a toin coss using this algorithm produce a strictly alternating pattern?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both work for list of non-unique elements as well:

```
def choice_without_repetition(lst):
    prev = None
    while True:
        i = random.randrange(len(lst))
        if i != prev:
            yield lst[i]
            prev = i
```

or

```
def choice_without_repetition(lst):
    i = 0
    while True:
        i = (i + random.randrange(1, len(lst))) % len(lst)
        yield lst[i]
```

Usage:

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
for x in choice_without_repetition(lst):
    print x
```

Answer (score 2):

Draw forever, never choosing the same item twice in a row:

```
import random

def choice_no_repeat(lst):
    random.shuffle(lst)
    last = lst[0]
    lst.pop(0)
    yield last
    while True:
        random.shuffle(lst)
        last, lst[0] = lst[0], last
        yield last

choice = choice_no_repeat([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
for _ in range(10):
    print(next(choice))
```

example output:

```
1
6
1
3
8
7
4
7
1
8
```

Answer (score 1):

You could shuffle the list randomly before iterating through the list. Then, after iterating through the list, sort it to get it back to it's original state:

```
import random

l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
random.shuffle(l)
for element in l:
    print(element)
l = sorted(l)
print(l)
```

**Output**

```
3
2
8
6
7
5
1
4
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Comment: That's not what the question asked for, since it specifically mentioned "so that I can avoid picking the same item in a row; but it should be added back again after".

Comment: This won't pick the same item twice in a row?

Comment: It will pick items from the list without ever choosing the same item twice.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: as the comment explains, this really answer a different question: how to draw M different numbers from an array of N.

If you don't mind using numpy, it has [`np.random.choice`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) which does exactly what you want:

> Generates a random sample from a given 1-D array

Specifying `replace=False` makes sure each element is only drawn once. If you draw all elements, this will effectively give you a permutation:

```
np.random.choice([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], 8, replace=False)
```

Comment: This answer will pick items from the list without ever choosing the same item twice. However, that is not what the question asked for, since it specifically mentioned "so that I can avoid picking the same item in a row; but it should be added back again after".